# What is the importance of the biquadratic interaction in the AKLT model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

The AKLT in a spin-1 Heisenberg chain can be realized when we introduce the bi-quadratic exchange interaction in addition to the bi-linear interaction. I would like understand this interaction more physically and where do such high order exchange interaction originate from. For example like a cartoon picture of the electrons and the orbitals of this bi-quadratic interaction?

Comment: I think more context is needed here...

Comment: I mean the Haldane phase in a spin-1 Heisenberg chain can be realized when we introduce the bi-quadratic exchange interaction in addition to the bi-linear interaction. I would like understand this interaction more physically and where do such high order exchange interaction originate from.

Comment: So add that (and maybe your current thoughts/understanding as well) to the body of the post, rather than a comment.

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): Consider spelling out abbreviations.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the biquadratic interaction to realize the Haldane phase. The Heisenberg spin-1 chain already does the job. Adding the biquadratic term allows one to have a parent Hamiltonian for the exact AKLT wavefunction. Here is a phase diagram for the bilinear-biquadratic Hamiltonian taken from http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1839, with the following Hamiltonian

$ H=\sum_i \cos\theta\mathbf{S}_i \cdot\mathbf{S}_{i+1}+\sin\theta (\mathbf{S}_i \cdot\mathbf{S}_{i+1})^2$

[[image: Phase diagram]]

Comment: Hello Meng, This partially answers my question. I am aware that introducing the bi-quadratic term gives us an SO(3) symmetric Hamiltonian for which there is an exact MPS representation i.e. the AKLT in this case.
 I should have been more careful with the terms and used AKLT instead of Haldane in my question.
 However, what I am really interested is to see something like a cartoon picture of this bi-quadratic interaction in terms of something like the electrons and the orbitals?

Comment: @user96952 Just go one more order in the t/U expansion and you will get bi-quadratic interaction.

Comment: @Everett You: Thanks, do you have any good reference on this? I am unsure where to look at.